# webdriver-io - Cannot init a new session

Tags: webdriver-io

Sometimes my selenium grid errors out with this error `Session [e4b60cfd-88f9-40ad-a14f-18ba46355a30] was terminated due to TIMEOUT"` and appears to be related to this issue in SeleniumHQ:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1557

In my webdriverio code, I can catch this exception like:

```
.getAttribute('something').then((onSuccess,onError))
```

And inside onError, I'm trying end the session like:

```
client.end().then(()=>{
  console.log("ending the session due to error");
});

or

client.session('delete').then(()=>{
  console.log("deleting the session due to error");
});
```

Both of these didn't work. Meaning, I never saw my console messages. Possible that the session was terminated already (based on the previous error message).

However, when I try to run the test again, getting this error:

```
Cannot init a new session, please end your current session first
```

Whats the proper way to end the session and handle this issue?